# Email Problem - mailq

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, email, sendmail

I have a problem with emails on my server. Almost all emails have stopped being received or sent.

I have tried flushing the mailq using `/usr/sbin/postfix flush` but no luck. I think it is connected with the following strange emails appearing in the queue:

```
C24CAEEBD4F*    1047 Mon Apr 11 07:40:01  root@ip-XXX-XXX-XX-XX.ip.secureserver.net
                                          root@ip-XXX-XXX-XX-XX.ip.secureserver.net
```

It appears that the entry above is trying to send an email to the server from the server (XXX-XXX-XX-XX= my IP). When the above items are in the mailq, the queue does not flush and no emails are sent or received.

The emails that I have put into the queue look like this:

```
3D30DEEBD97*    3282 Mon Apr 11 07:41:05  noreply@mydomain.com
                                          recip@anothersite.com
```

When the queue only contains the emails I have put in, it works fine. I am using PHP Pear Mail to manage my emails which has been running fine up until now. I am also running Apache 2 (CentOS 5.5).

**Does any one know what the strange entries in the mailq are and why they are in there?**

Thank you,

Chris.

Comment: Can you post some more log info about these strange mails and a bit more description about who uses the box please ? My first thought was maybe the box has been compromised and my second was Postfix has hit resource limits. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan - Hi. How do I get more info on the strange entries? There are only a handful of mailboxes that use it at. We are not sending a vast number of emails.

Comment: This should do it: `cat /var/log/mail.log | grep XXX-XXX-XX-XX` where the Xs are the strange IPs.

Comment: The IP in the mailq is my server's IP. Should it be there? I get the following error with that command : `cat: /var/log/mail.log: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Centos logs live here: /var/log/maillog (not mail.log).

I'd expect something like this from your mail logs.

`Apr 11 15:22:11 MailBox postfix/qmgr[7061]: 8B48902: from=<me@ross.com>, size=1784, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

`Apr 11 15:22:11 MyMailBox postfix/local[7829]: E5E8901: to=<me@gmail.com>, orig_to=<me@me.com>, relay=local, delay=1, delays=0.38/0/0/0.67, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 8B4902)`

Hopefully that will shed some light.

Please be selective about what you paste and keep the lines clear like I've done otherwise I might go cross-eyed :-). You could use pastie.org if it helps.

-- edit --

A couple of things I've spotted:

`fatal: main.cf configuration error: mailbox_size_limit is smaller than message_size_limit`

`warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/local: bad command startup -- throttling`

Give me another minute.

Comment: No problem, give me a minute to look over it.

Comment: OK, hopefully this is it: please run `postconf -d | grep mailbox_size_limit` and copy me to the result. We'll increase `mailbox_size_limit` in a second once you've passed that on (I found this here: `http://syscp-forum.org/index.php?topic=3984.0`)

Comment: OK, mailbox_size_limit = 51200000

Comment: Basically the Server was dying because one e-mail (at the maximum size set) was larger than a Mailbox so there would be nowhere to put the mail if it was large, even one mail.

Comment: Okay, have you used a text editor before ? Can you add `mailbox_size_limit = 101200000` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf'`and then run `/etc/init.d/postfix restart` ?

Comment: Right OK, so shall I increase the `mailbox_size_limit` or decrease the `message_size_limit`. Do you know which email was breaching the `message_size_limit`?

Comment: Sorry, just seen your message. Will do now. 1 sec.

Comment: Sorry, I think we're cross-posting :-): Can you add `mailbox_size_limit = 101200000` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and then run `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`

Comment: It's not just one e-mail, I would guess it's a self-protection thing for Postfix.

Comment: If that fixes it then it might be worth editing your comment with the `pastie.org` link and removeing that link - just in case - it has some private-ish info in it.

Comment: I have added the line to the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and restarted postfix. Unfortunately, the strange emails are still appearing in the queue (after I cleared it and tested it). Pastbin link removed as well... thank you.

Comment: However, when I run the `postconf -d | grep mailbox_size_limit` I will get : `mailbox_size_limit = 51200000` and not the new value. I will double check the `main.cf`.

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned with those mails (unless you're an open relay, you can test here: http://www.checkor.com) but more with the fatal error in the logs. Has it stopped appearing now ? Run `cat /var/log/maillog | grep fatal` on the command line and see when the last `fatal` entry is.

Comment: It was a minute ago :(.

Comment: If you see the old value it's probably duplicated in `main.cf` I would guess. Postfix is pretty clever, just try running `postfix reload` in case it's not restarting correctly.

Comment: Don't worry see above :-)

Comment: I have searched for it `main.cf` and it only appears once at the bottom where I have defined it. I have also tried `postfix reload` but no luck.

Comment: Okay, in terms of Postfix starting up a for a while and failing the logs say that's the problem. Hold on a second.

Comment: Okay, a couple of things to check. Please remove your added line and change it to `mailbox_size_limit = 0` then `postfix reload`.

Comment: Looking better!! I have not had any fatal errors in the log or strange emails appear so far.

Comment: Some emails are hanging around longer that I expected through. Some have been in for 4 minutes. Is that normal?

Comment: Great news. I think the odd mails were a red herring. The `= 0` setting isn't ideal unless you're enforcing quotas for users from what I gather. Now it's accepting the new value, ideally you should set it to the `101200000` limit or similar. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't focus too much on the queue - mail is complex these days, with greylisting and the like, so mails can be delayed for ages. I'd suggest using a completely unrelated mail account (like gmail.com or fastmail.fm) and do some send and receive checks to make sure it's happy.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working :-)

Comment: Great great answer & support. Really really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help. I know what it's like: e-mail is one of those things ... you're lost without it :-)